# Limit for offline queueing in mqtt

Tags: mqtt

Is there any way we limit the number of messages stored in the mqtt offline queue ?
Also can the messages be stored in LIFO form.

Answer (score 0):

All those details would be implementation specifics for the broker you are using.

If I remember correctly the [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html) doesn't make any comment on how the queue of offline messages should be handled and it is implied there is no limit.

As you've not mentioned which broker you are using it's impossible to answer this definitively, but some brokers have plugable persistence layers (e.g. [aedes](https://github.com/mcollina/aedes)) that would allow you to implement what ever offline queuing mechanism you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was actually looking for something like [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/327) , but in python.